# Is "Where do I find the Java JDK Source code for JDK 1.8?" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, reopen-closed

I posted this question some time ago: [Where do I find the Java JDK Source code for JDK 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732226/where-do-i-find-the-java-jdk-source-code-for-jdk-1-8)

It was tagged to be closed for being off-topic. I protested because although not specifically about programming, I think that the JDK is a tool very specific to programmers and programming, and therefore fits the "*unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming*" exception. I appended an explanation to the end of the question as to why I felt it was on topic as suggested, and multiple users voted the question re-opened.

Since then the question has been closed again for the same reason, with the edit explaining why it was on-topic removed. This was done by a Java programmer with a lot of reputation, which leads me to wonder if my question is off topic - but I can't for the life of me see how it doesn't fall under a "tools used for programming" type question! I don't want to get into an open-close-open war with somebody with more rep, particularly if I'm wrong, so please educate me!

Comment: You got 4 answers, they all say the same thing.  Why do you want a 5th answer to say the same thing?  That Oracle's business practices are not considered on topic at SO shouldn't be terribly surprising, SO users like happy answers that don't recommend copyright and legal contract violations.

Comment: Questions asking us to ... find... a library are off topic. There's no *unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming* in the current close reason.

Comment: I'm a little on the fence on this one. On the one hand a source distribution being part of a download package does not seem on-topic on a Q&A site, it would have been better suited for the Oracle forums. But on the other hand the src.zip can be an important Java code debugging aid especially inside an IDE.

Comment: And this question proves what I said all the way back: not because it's a "tool commonly used by programmers" immediately makes it on topic, it has to comply with "a **practical**, **answerable problem** that is unique to software development" and not violate the [/help/don-t-ask]

Comment: @Hans Passant  I'd like to address your comment first and separately as I think that you are mistaken and may be giving misleading information. Firstly, the answers are not the same. Secondly, copyright is not violated, nor is a legal contract violated. Also, I don't wish any further answers - the question was answered, with what I would regard as a "happy" answer. It explains how to get the source code which is (I believe) unintentionally missing from the Zip.

Comment: @Hans Passant Ah, I see where your comment came from. The answer which showed where the source could *legally* be obtained from Oracle (it is in all of the Linux zips) was deleted, then the question deleted, after I posted this question, which I guess makes this all moot.

Comment: Well, I guess the question is gone now. I think it made SO stronger. I don't think it was off topic, as I don't think of the JDK as just a "library", though I accept Tensibai's comment that it was offiste, so if that is all it takes, then it is off. I do think deleting the accepted answer before deleting the question was a bit rich though.

Comment: Also, why does this not apply to questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code ? (Please don't go and immediately close that question simply because I asked - that Was one of many many similar questions on SO, I just chose it because it is the first protected one I saw, and it has an answer to my question in the comments).

Answer (score 11):

Quoting [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis is mine in both quotes):

> - software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is**
> - a **practical**, **answerable problem** that is unique to software development

Finding the source of the JDK is exactly the close reason of your question:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow..."

The answers can't give more than an external resource or guidance to get an external resource, which is likely to break at any point in time. This is exactly why 'off-site' resources are off topic on SO.

Comment: OK, so this reason makes sense I guess (though I don't like the idea). If a resource is not available on SO itself, then any advice as to where to find it is off topic. I do think though that the question is answerable (and indeed was), that it was practical (as the number of visits would suggest), but I cannot guarantee that Oracle won't go under tomorrow, so it is fair to say that the link may break, however unlikely (Sun was sold after all).

Comment: @timbo That's more than advice to where to find it has good chances to become obsolete, so there's no reason to have it in a knowledge base. As demonstrated by answers in your question, some JDK versions have the source zip, some has not. "Practical" doesn't mean interesting, it means it solves a problem in a long term manner. Said another way: StackOverflow is not the right place for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

***Regarding the edit:***

The reason for the edit (Rev. 6, Rollback to Rev. 4) was that your edit (Rev. 5) **did nothing but introduce a ton of noise** (noise = unnecessary information etc.).

If the community consensus is "OFF-TOPIC", you shouldn't add text to your question explaining why it should be reopened. Instead, you should post a question on meta, or explain it via comments.

Comment: I agree my edit added noise. Not sure that the community concensus was to close; it was re-opened. It was closed again much later.

Comment: @timbo - And, I should mention that closing a question on SO is NOT a consensus processes at all, so the fact that it was closed is NOT an indicator of a consensus for anything.  It just takes a couple people who vote to close and it's closed.  There's no vote to "not close".  There are only votes to reopen, but there could have been 100 viewers before it was closed that thought it was a good on-topic question.  And, once it's been closed, very few people ever visit it to decide whether its worthy of reopening.  So, nothing about closing is consensus oriented.

Comment: I mean, that's simply not true. A very large portion of close votes simply age away, due to no consensus.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Seth argued it was community consensus, 6 years ago. If anything, your point supports my post.